# How to implement a caption and photographer credit with <figure>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I would like to create a standard way to provide an image with an alt tag for accessibility and SEO, a descriptive caption, **and a separate element for a photographer credit**. It appears that only one [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) is allowed per `<figure>` and it must be the first or last element, so that rules out doing this:

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/500/280" alt="a handsome pooch stares at the camera">
    <figcaption class="caption">George, the doggo</figcaption>
    <figcaption class="photo-credit">Photo: Jane Doe</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Which of these is best, and why?

### 1

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/500/280" alt="a handsome pooch stares at the camera">
    <div class="photo-credit">Photo: Jane Doe</div>
    <figcaption class="caption">George, the doggo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

### 2

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/500/280" alt="a handsome pooch stares at the camera">
    <figcaption>
        <span class="caption">George, the doggo</span>
        <span class="photo-credit">Photo: Jane Doe</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

### 3

Something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a variation of option 2, where you add punctuation to the contents of the inline elements to make them read better as sentences.

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://placedog.net/500/280" alt="a handsome pooch stares at the camera">
  <figcaption>
    <span class="caption">George, the doggo.</span>
    <i class="photo-credit">Photo by Jane Doe.</i>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) spec describes the `<figure>` element as follows (emphasis mine):

> The HTML `<figure>` (Figure With Optional Caption) element represents **self-contained content**, potentially with an optional caption, which is specified using the (`<figcaption>`) element. The figure, its caption, and its contents are referenced as a single unit.

Placing the photo credit outside of the `<figure>` (as another answer suggests) would make it no longer "self-contained", as the credit is an integral part of the photograph. The `<figcaption>` element is the most appropriate place for the credit, as long as you word it in such a way that readers won't confuse it with part of the caption.

Using an `<i>` element for the credit can further separate it (both visually and semantically) from the caption, as:

> The HTML `<i>` element represents a range of text that is set off from the normal text for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very personal choice and all your proposals are correct. However,  I guess the`figure` component should only accept two children: `img` and `figcaption`. I also think `figcaption` must only do one thing: show the figure caption. If I need a space to credits, so, I need to implement it.

Below my implementation:

```css
.photo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

figure figcaption {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
}

.photo-credit {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
}

.photo-credit:before {
  content: 'Photo: ';
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/500/280" alt="a handsome pooch stares at the camera">
    <figcaption class="caption">George, the doggo</figcaption>
   </figure>
  <span class="photo-credit">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting way to do it... feels like a lot of markup for what's being accomplished. I guess it is a personal choice at some point, like you said. I was just curious if there was an industry standard for this kind of thing, but I guess not.

Comment: Hi @squarecandy, well, I worked in a lot of companies developing front end interfaces and I never have seen any specific standard for that. Sometimes is better to have more code and be clear and consistent. Cheers

Comment: @PabloDarde "However, I guess the `figure` component should only accept two children: `img` and `figcaption`." This is not true. A figure can have as many elements with in it as necessary. The only restriction is on the number and placement of the `figcaption`—there can only be one, and it must be first or last.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably go with [`<cite />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite) since MDN describes it as follows:

> The **HTML Citation element (`<cite>`)** is used to describe a reference to a cited creative work, and must include the title of that work. The reference may be in an abbreviated form according to context-appropriate conventions related to citation metadata.

Comment: I believe <cite> is intended for citing external works, not for crediting the creator of the current item. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote

Comment: How do you define "external works"? If the photographer is neither the site owner nor staff, they are somewhat external, aren't they?

Comment: It's to cite a work, not an author - so if you have a blog post that is discussing "Brave New World" and then you put a quote from the book in, `blockquote` goes around the quote and `cite` goes around "Brave New World", not "Aldous Huxley". In this case, the book is not the blog post - the book is a work being quoted/referenced - that's what I mean by external. And the author is not the work - note that the Mozilla example puts `cite` around the title only.

Comment: It says it right in the MDN quote you posted: "<cite> is used to describe a reference to a cited creative work, and must include the title of that work"

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I misread the emphasis of your answer. Maybe you can use a microformat like [hCard](http://html5doctor.com/microformats/#hcard) or microdata like [schema.org](https://schema.org/) instead.

Comment: Yeah, schema.org is actually a great idea. I guess it would matter less if you use <span> vs <em> vs <figcaption> if you just mark it up with `itemprop="author"` or `itemprop="creator"`within a `https://schema.org/Photograph` on the <figure>